# BitVector operations impossible

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitvector

I want to perform an xor operation on two BitVectors. While trying to turn one of the strings into a bitVector to then proceed into the xor operation, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x91'
```

How can I bypass this problem? I just want to xor two expressions, but one of them is a string, and it needs to be turned to a bitvector first right? However, trying to turn the string into BitVector is giving the error above.

```
    to_be_xored = BitVector.BitVector(bitstring= variable)
```

where variable is the string, and to_be_xored is the desired Bitvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitstring` is for sequences of `'0'`s and `'1'`s. To use text use `textstring` instead.